# Regarding MarkLogic memory update issue

Tags: marklogic

I am creating a document and updating it in memory. But it is not updating the document i.e. not deleting ‘file-text’ element from the created document. Below is the code.
Can you please let me know what I am missing here.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at   "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";

let $createArchDoc := xdmp:document-insert("/abc.xml",doc("/xyz.xml"))
let $createArchDoc := mem:node-delete($createArchDoc/document/file-text)
return $createArchDoc/document
```

I  also tried

```
let $createArchDoc := xdmp:document-insert("/abc.xml",doc("/xyz.xml"))
let $myNewDoc := doc("/abc.xml")
let $myNewDoc := mem:node-delete($myNewDoc/document/file-text)
return $myNewDoc/document
```

Answer (score 4):

The `in-mem-update` library is meant to be used on structures that have not been persisted to database yet. You will have to apply the mem calls first, and persist after.

Also, `xdmp:document-insert` returns empty sequence, so `$createArchDoc` would be empty in both cases.

You are probably look for something like the following (untested):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at   "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";

let $createArchDoc := doc("/xyz.xml")
let $createArchDoc := mem:node-delete($createArchDoc/document/file-text)
let $_ := xdmp:document-insert("/abc.xml",$createArchDoc)
return $createArchDoc/document
```

HTH!